# globally defined function and restriction of a differential form

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the 1-form $a=p_1dx_1+p_2dx_2-H(p_1,p_2)dt$ defined on $R^5=(p_1,x_1,p_2,x_2,t)$ where $H$ is a globally defined smooth function that depends only on the coordinates $p_1$ and $p_2$.

(a) Compute the differential $da$. Is it true that a is a differential of globally defined smooth function on $R^5$?

(b) Compute the restriction of $a$ [the original problem here is $da$, but I think this is a typo, right?] to the 3-dim plane($p_1=4,p_2=5$). Is it true that the restriction of $a$ to this 3-dim plane is a differential of a smooth function defined on this plane. If the answer of the previous question is "yes" find the corresponding function.

My work:
(a)
$$da=dp_1\wedge dx_1+dp_2\wedge dx_2-H_{p_1}dp_1\wedge dt-H_{p_2}dp_2\wedge dt$$
(b)
restriction of $a$ is $4dx_1+5dx_2-H(4,5)dt$. And $a$ is a differential of $4x_1+5x_2-H(4,5)t$.

My question is:

(a) How to determine if $a$ is a differential of a function? I don't know how to answer this, except for randomly choosing some functions to take derivative to see, but I think this must not be the right way to do this.

(b) Is my work in part(b) right? Just so simple? I cannot believe it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If $a = df$ for some function $f$, then $da = d(df) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you! So I calculate this, the first two terms are zero, the rest two are $-H_{p_1p_2}dp_2\wedge dp_1\wedge dt-H_{p_2p_1}dp_1\wedge dp_2\wedge dt$ and thus the sum is zero. So it is exact?

Comment: But how do I find the original function?

Comment: Well, it seems that the problem did not ask me to find the original function...

Comment: What you are doing is $d(da)$, which must be zero. But as $da\neq 0$, $a$ cannot be $df$.

Comment: OK, now I understand your logic. Thank you very much!